# Expanding a generating function in a series

Tags: generating-functions

For a given recurrence relation the generating function is **A(x)=$\frac{x}{(1-x)(1-2x)}$**.

Then the book says that if we want to find an explicit formula for the $a_n$'s we
would have to expand **A(x)** in a series. The partial fraction of **A(x)** is $$ x \{\frac{2}{1-2x}-\frac{1}{1-x}\}$$ and this is clear to me. But how did the author expand this 
 $$ x \{\frac{2}{1-2x}-\frac{1}{1-x}\} = \{2x+2^2x^2+2^3x^3+...\}-\{x+x^2+x^3+..\} $$

Hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try deriving Taylor-series of $2/(1-2x)$ and $1/(1-x)$ with expansion in $0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)(1-2x)}=\frac{1}{1-2x}-\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\frac{1}{1-x} =1+x+x^2 +... $ for $x<1$.

Answer (score -2):

It only took me a few more minutes to get it. From the geometric series evaluation, we know that
$\sum_nx^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|=1$.

And know taking the summation of our partial fraction : $ \frac{1}{1-2x}-\frac{1}{1-x}$ we get

$$ \sum_n \frac{1}{1-2x}-\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_n\frac{1}{1-2x}-\sum_n\frac{1}{1-x} = (2x)^n - x^n$$ and hence we have $$\{2x+2^2x^2+2^3x^3+...\}-\{x+x^2+x^3+...\}$$